# Affine transformation in d3.geo (Euler angles rotation)

Tags: d3.js, rotation, geo, d3.geo

I would like to perform a counter-clockwise rotation of a country polygon about an origin in d3.geo.

For example, let's rotate Italy -7.2 degrees around a point with λ=0.5, φ=49.9. First, we need to [transform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/21696) those Euler angles into an Affine transformation parameters. In our case, the parameters will be:

```
affine(0.5, 49.9, -7.2)
   scaleX      rotY    transX       rotX    scaleY   transY
0.9921147 0.1253332 -6.250186 -0.1253332 0.9921147 0.456143
```

When I use QGIS Affine Transform plugin with such parameters the resulting map is [image: here].

When I apply the same parameters to `projection.stream` in d3.js, the result is very different (and incorrect): https://bl.ocks.org/memoryfull/946a8172d074a865c4ff

I am handling the projection stream correctly in my code, because an (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0) Affine transformation yields an expected result of no transformation.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: References: [On embedded projection streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557724/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-d3s-projection-stream), [Mike Bostock's example on custom projections](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5663666), [QGIS parameters used](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tcTBy.png)

Comment: It looks like it's been rotated about the origin (top left) of the entire SVG element  in your code. What you probably need is to translate Italy to the origin, apply your transformation, and then translate back

Comment: @RolandHeath thank you for the suggestion. I am afraid this is not the case. It would be had I done a simple transformation of Italy, without a second stream:
`.attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.transform({ point: function(x, y) { this.stream.point(0.992 * x + 0.125 * y - 6.25, -0.125 * x + 0.992 * y + 0.456); } }) ));`